# Can pgbouncer re-read /etc/hosts file without restart

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, hosts, pgbouncer

Is there a way for `pgbouncer` to force to re-read `/etc/hosts` file without restart?  I have added a new server to `/etc/hosts` and I want `pgbouncer` to connect to the new server with a minimum of hassle.

I know issuing `RELOAD;` command will force to re-read configuration file, but it seems that this does not apply to `/etc/hosts`.  Also running command `SHOW DNS_HOSTS` (after changes in configuration and `/etc/hosts`) new *hostname* value would appear, but *addrs* value is left blank.

`pgbouncer` version: 1.7.2 running on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I thought reload should reread /etc/hosts. also if `dns_max_ttl` is not set to too long values, it should reread itself... `SHOW DNS_HOSTS` reads dns cache - if addrs is blank, maybe you have a bad value in `/etc/hosts`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun The entry in `/etc/hosts` is valid, since I can `ssh`/`psql` into it using hostname.  In my case, `dns_max_ttl` is set to a default 15 seconds.

Comment: `Hostnames are resolved on connect time, the result is cached per dns_max_ttl parameter.` did you try to connect to databse on that hostname?..

Comment: Yes, I did using `psql`.  There was no problem.  Only `pgbouncer` cannot connect.  After restarting `pgbouncer` the hosts file is re-read and there is no problem.  I just wonder, if this can be done without the `pgbouncer` restart.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't read this as instruction for usage. This is more academical interest - what you need to do to make pgbouncer 1.7 to reread `/etc/hosts` without restart:

first demo:

```
pgbouncer=# show dns_hosts;
 hostname | ttl |    addrs
----------+-----+-------------
 one      |   6 | 127.0.0.3:0
(1 row)

pgbouncer=# \! sudo sed -i 's/127.0.0.3/127.0.0.2/' /etc/hosts
pgbouncer=# pause test;
PAUSE
pgbouncer=# kill test;
KILL
pgbouncer=# resume test;
RESUME
pgbouncer=# \! psql -p 6432 -h 127.0.0.1 -U vao -d test -c "\! tail -1 /etc/hosts"
Password for user vao:
127.0.0.2   one
pgbouncer=# show dns_hosts;
 hostname | ttl |    addrs
----------+-----+-------------
 one      |   7 | 127.0.0.2:0
(1 row)

pgbouncer=# \! sudo sed -i 's/127.0.0.2/127.0.0.12/' /etc/hosts
pgbouncer=# pause test;
PAUSE
pgbouncer=# kill test;
KILL
pgbouncer=# resume test;
RESUME
pgbouncer=# \! psql -p 6432 -h 127.0.0.1 -U vao -d test -c "\! tail -1 /etc/hosts"
Password for user vao:
127.0.0.12   one
pgbouncer=# show dns_hosts;
 hostname | ttl |    addrs
----------+-----+--------------
 one      |  10 | 127.0.0.12:0
(1 row)
```

Now why:
`RELOAD` rereads config, thus won't help here. `dns_max_ttl` controls roundroubin between several reselves returned by dns, thus won't play here. Recalling

> Hostnames are resolved on connect time

I make an assumption that in order to reinitiate connection I need to drop existing connections (so connection would not be taken from the pool) - two way to do it - either restart pgbouncer or `KILL db` - isolating the impact to only one db from `pgbouncer.ini [databases]` section. So I added

```
test = host=one port=5432 dbname=t
```

to it and

```
127.0.0.3   one
```

to `/etc/hosts`. The rest is in demo.

I would interpret this answer as a cheat - I don't restart pgbouncer, but yet all existing connections to wanted db need to be dropped. (of course we don't affect other databases clients connected, but still). So the answer would be - yes, you can do it without restart, yet all connections to that db will be dropped, thus you can't do it without dropping existing connections to the host that has changed. just `PAUSE + RESUME` combination won't help here as

> Hostnames are resolved on connect time